# Why doesn't my simple if-statement render false in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I call a function like this:

```
call_facebook(103138046395999, "samåkning.se", "http://www.facebook.com/samakning", "page");
call_facebook(16089699074, "Jag ska köra bil, vem vill åka med", "http://www.facebook.com/groups/16089699074/", "grupp")
```

The function looks like this:

```
function call_facebook(id, name, link, type){
  //snip
  console.log(type)
  if (type = "grupp"){
    var postid=fbposts[fbpost].id.split("_");
    return "https://www.facebook.com/groups/"+postid[0]+"/permalink/"+postid[1]+'/'
  }
  else {
    return fbposts[fbpost].actions[0].link;
  }
}
//snip
};
```

I have confirmed that they have different type arguments, but still the first case `if (type = "grupp")` always ends up `true`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single equals character (`=`) does not compare. It assigns! Therefore, your `if` statement always assigns `"grupp"` into `type` and returns `true`.

Use `==` or `===` to compare.

Comment: what's the difference between == and ===?

Comment: `===` checks if the arguments are of the same type

Comment: @KristofferNolgren `==` will perform implicit type conversion but `===` won't; think of `===` as "**really** equal" and `==` as "conceptually equal". Sort-of.

Comment: @Kristoffer: Better read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant

```
if (type == "grupp"){
```

You have to use `==` to compare values. Just a single `=` is used to assign values.