# Finding values in options and editing css style using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My java script, which I got from a stack overflow question looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function search() {
    var a = document.getElementByClassName("s1");
    var b = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
    if (b = 1) {
        document.getElementById("vmh").style.visibility = hidden
    }
    }
</script>
```

and there is a button that activates the function search, but the visibility is not changing

Comment: Can you also include the markup for the `select` tag?

Comment: div class="title">
 <label>select a dificulty</label>
 <select class="s1">
  <option value="1">easy</option>
  <option value="2">medium</option>
  <option value="3">hard</option>
 </select>
</div>

Comment: `getElementByClassName` returns a **list** of elements, not just one element ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)). Also note that `=` is **assignment**, not comparison ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178605/why-doesnt-my-simple-if-statement-render-false-in-javascript)). And `value` is always a string ([more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945779/incorrect-result-in-javascript-calculation/32945816#32945816)). Finally, unless `hidden` is a variable, it should be in quotes: `"hidden"`.

Comment: If you got that function from a stack overflow question, I sure hope the answers explained the issues with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement is not comparing values, but is instead assigning a value. `b = 1` assigns `1` to the variable `b`. Instead, you'll want to use a comparison operator `if (b == 1)`.

Secondly, the `hidden` should be wrapped in quotes. Currently you are assigning `hidden` to the `visibility` property, but `hidden` does not appear to be a variable. Instead, you'll do `visibility = 'hidden'`.